# using grep with multiple entries in r to find matching strings

Tags: r

If I have a vector of strings:

```
dd <- c("sflxgrbfg_sprd_2011","sflxgrbfg_sprd2_2011","sflxgrbfg_sprd_2012")
```

and want to find the entires with '2011' in the string I can use

```
ifiles <- dd[grep("2011",dd)]
```

How do I search for entries with a combination of strings included, without using a loop?

For example, I would like to find the entries with both '2011' and 'sprd' in the string, which in this case will only return

```
sflxgrbfg_sprd_2011
```

How can this be done? I could define a variable

```
toMatch <- c('2011','sprd)
```

and then loop through the entries but I was hoping there was a better solution?

Note: To make this useful for different strings. Is it also possible to to determine which entries have these strings without them being in the order shown. For example, 'sflxlgrbfg_2011_sprd'

Comment: Do you patterns other than those specified in the example?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more specific. I've added a note. I basically mean any number of strings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find more than one pattern, try indexing with a logical value rather than the number.  That way you can create an "and" condition, where only the string with both patterns will be extracted.

```
ifiles <- dd[grepl("2011",dd) & grepl("sprd_",dd)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  grep('2011_sprd|sprd_2011', dd, value=TRUE)
 #[1] "sflxgrbfg_sprd_2011"  "sflxlgrbfg_2011_sprd"
```

Or using an example with more patterns

```
 grep('(?<=sprd_).*(?=2011)|(?<=2011_).*(?=sprd)', dd1,
             value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "sflxgrbfg_sprd_2011"       "sflxlgrbfg_2011_sprd"     
 #[3] "sfxl_2011_14334_sprd"      "sprd_124334xsff_2011_1423"
```

#### data

```
dd <- c("sflxgrbfg_sprd_2011","sflxgrbfg_sprd2_2011","sflxgrbfg_sprd_2012", 
"sflxlgrbfg_2011_sprd")

dd1 <- c(dd,  "sfxl_2011_14334_sprd", "sprd_124334xsff_2011_1423")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scalable solution, you can use `lapply`, `Reduce` and `intersect` to:

1. For each expression in `toMatch`, find the indices of all matches in `dd`.
2. Keep only those indices that are found for all expressions in `toMatch`.

```r
dd <- c("sflxgrbfg_sprd_2011","sflxgrbfg_sprd2_2011","sflxgrbfg_sprd_2012")
dd <- c(dd, "sflxgrbfh_sprd_2011")
toMatch <- c('bfg', '2011','sprd')

dd[Reduce(intersect, lapply(toMatch, grep, dd))]
#> [1] "sflxgrbfg_sprd_2011"  "sflxgrbfg_sprd2_2011"
```

Created on 2018-03-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).