# grep function in r with two matches

Tags: r, regex, subset

looking how to use grep function with multiple matches. 
this is my data:

```
trial<-c("k_d","k_ed","k_eda","b_ed","b_eda")
```

I would like to select cases that contain both "k" and "ed". Using grep with "&" does not work and using "|" instead of "&" gives of course this result:

```
grep("k|ed",trial)

[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there any solution to reach a resutl like this?:

```
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: Do you have other patterns. `grep('k[^a-z]ed', trial)` works for this example, or `which(grepl('k', trial) & grepl('ed', trial))`

Comment: Or maybe `grep('(?=k).*ed.*', trial, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: or `grep(".*k.*ed.*|.*ed.*k.*", trial)`?

Comment: your solution and @akrun second solution worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: This one's somewhat cryptic, but it works, too: `which(grepl("ed",trial)*grepl("k",trial)!=0)`

Comment: check my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761553/using-grep-with-multiple-entries-in-r-to-find-mathcing-strings/30761798#30761798

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match if some text contains both 1 string and another string can be written as

```
grep("k.*ed",trial)
```

This Iimplies a specific word order though. To check substring presence regardless of word order with regex you can use anchored lookaheads:

```
grep("^(?=[^k]*k)(?=.*ed)",trial, perl=T)
```